# Chained calls to Angular's router.navigate() behavior regarding query parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I've been running in some confusing behavior when chaining calls to the Angular Router's navigate() function. My use case is a large application that updates part of its state in the URL, where several services are responsible for managing their state.

As such, we may have several calls to `navigate([], {queryParams: ..., queryParamsHandling: 'merge'})` within the same zone.js execution window.

While this usually works fine, I run into weird behavior when a router command is provided in between, such as [the following stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-playground-chained-navigation?file=app/routing-examples/routing-examples.component.ts):

```js
this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: {} }); // <-- [1]

this.router.navigate([], { // <-- [2]
  queryParams: { foo: "fooValue", bar: "barValue" },
  queryParamsHandling: "merge"
});

this.router.navigate(["some"]); // <-- [3]

this.router.navigate([], { // <-- [4]
  queryParams: { foo: "newFooValue", baz: "bazValue" },
  queryParamsHandling: "merge"
});
```

**What I expect from this** is `{foo: 'newFooValue', bar: 'barValue', baz: 'bazValue'}`, however it looks like the 2nd call to the router is simply dropped as `bar` parameter is never propagated.

Adding `{ queryParamsHandling: "merge" }` to the 3rd call does not change this behavior, same with `"preserve"`.

How can I chain such calls to the Router and get the expected result? Do I need to defer my `this.router.navigate` call in a `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not a fun of promises but I believe promises need to be chained if you need them to execute one after another. Something like

```typescript
  triggerChainedNavigation() {
    console.log("Beginning chained navigation");
    const firstRouting = () =>
      this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: { foo: "fooValue", bar: "barValue" },
        queryParamsHandling: "merge"
      });

    const secondRouting = () => {
      this.router.navigate(["some_route"], {
        queryParamsHandling: "preserve"
      });
    };
    const thirdRouting = () => {
      this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: { foo: "newFooValue", baz: "bazValue" },
        queryParamsHandling: "merge"
      });
    };
    this.router
      .navigate([], { queryParams: {} })
      .then(firstRouting)
      .then(secondRouting)
      .then(thirdRouting);
  }
```

See [this Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-playground-chained-navigation-waws65?file=app%2Frouting-examples%2Frouting-examples.component.ts)